# text relocations in shared objects?

Tags: linux, elf

when I compile the following code (file named d.c) using gcc

```
int var=10;

void fun( void ) {
  var++;
  int a=var;
}
```

with

```
gcc -c -o d.o -fPIC d.c
```

and call readelf -S there is a reloction section called .rela.text for the .text section

if I link the file to a shared object (reloctest.so) with

```
gcc  -shared d.o -o reloctest.so
```

the relocation section vanishes

Is it guaranteed that there are no relocation for the .text segment in shared objects? I think yes (due to relocations were added for PLT and DYN) but I'm not sure

Thanks for any answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically yes.

If you want to fully understand it you should read [understanding elf](http://www.linuxforums.org/articles/understanding-elf-using-readelf-and-objdump_125.html).